# Update strings for all cmdexec Jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-agent, jobs

Does anyone know if it's possible, (and furthermore advisable) to update all cmdexec strings in jobs on a server?

We'd like to change our logging location, and in principle I'd think this could be done very simply by changing the `/O "\\LOCATION\file.log"` strings.

I can see how you'd do that in fact

```
USE MSDB
GO
update dbo.sysjobsteps
set [command] = replace([command], '\\OLDLOCATION\... ', '\\NEWLOCATION\... ')
WHERE...
```

BUT I've had it drummed into me that you should never update the sys tables manually, so the idea of doing this makes me beyond nervous. For anything else I'd use the dbo.sp_update_job proc *(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188745.aspx for those who've strayed here looking for something else job related),* but that procedure doesn't seem to be able to handle this.

I have a hunch that this might possibly be an exception to the "Never Update the Sys Tables" rule though? I can't imagine that the cmdexec string is implied in any further relations in the way, for example, enabled/disabled status evidently is. Wishful thinking?

So I don't know for sure, and I can't seem to find out. Anyone know or have any experience with this?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Do you mean that a job can be enabled separately from the schedule(s) that govern it? That is very much by design and not redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, this is one of those operations that would definitely benefit from PowerShell.  All you'd need to do is gather the list of job steps that have your old string (in this case, your old location) and replace it with the new string (read: new location).

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") |
    Out-Null

$OldLocation = "<YourOldLocation>"
$NewLocation = "<YourNewLocation>"

$SqlServerName = "localhost"    # by default this will look at the local default instance
$SqlServer = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($SqlServerName)

# loop through all of the SQL Server Agent Jobs on the instance
foreach ($Job in $SqlServer.JobServer.Jobs) {

    # loop through each Job Step on the current Job
    foreach ($JobStep in $Job.JobSteps) {

        # test to see if the Job Step Command text contains your original string
        if ($JobStep.Command.Contains($OldLocation)) {
            $JobStep |
                Select-Object Parent, Name, Command

            # the below two lines would make the change to the new string and apply them
            #$JobStep.Command = $JobStep.Command.Replace($OldLocation, $NewLocation)
            #$JobStep.Alter()
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:  This is sample code and should thoroughly be tested in a non-production environment.  Ensure that your previous data is backed up, and that you are positive the change is the desirable outcome.**

All this code does it loops through all your jobs on a specific instance.  If the job step command contains a certain string, then it will show you what job it belongs to, the name of the step, and the command containing the string.  I have deliberately commented out the command modification lines so that the code only actually identifies which steps contain your string.

You can also narrow your search by adding additional conditional clauses to the `if` block.  For instance, if you just want to check `CmdExec` jobs, add this with an `-and` conditional check:

```
$JobStep.SubSystem -eq [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.AgentSubSystem]::CmdExec
```

This is simply one way to do this.  I will stress my point again: *make sure you test out this theory and execution far away from production, and ensure that you can revert changes with the necessary backup.*

Comment: thanks, this is great. I'll have a look through this tomorrow and try to get my head around it. I've never used powershell before but a few things have come up lately where it seems like it would be incredibly useful. We're working on a test server doing some investigations on a new server setup at the moment so we're in a good position for me to learn without destroying!

Comment: Excellent, that is good to hear.  PowerShell is becoming a requirement (in my honest opinion) for managing large environments.  At the very least, it makes tasks like this relatively simply to accomplish.  Good luck, and if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Cheers, appreciate it.

Comment: Just to clarify, this isn't doing anything differently than the set-based `UPDATE` in the OP's question - it still applies an `UPDATE` to `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps`, it just does it one row at a time.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Indirectly, sure.  But running a trace you'll see it's really calling `msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep`.  And yes, that stored proc does update the `msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps` table but there are a handful of other checks that the stored procedure call does.  I agree with you, Aaron, but I'll always choose the "API" route instead of direct table DML.

Comment: I guess. I prefer a set-based update than calling a stored procedure multiple times, if I know there isn't anything else I want to do. I can't imagine what checks are being made by the stored procedure that would be beneficial for me to go step by step instead of a single update.

Comment: Good to see this discussion. As I say below Thomas, events have played out such that I haven't time to understand powershell for this task, but ordinarily I think I agree I'd be much more comfortable relying on the proven processes of the API. Getting to grips with powershell is definitely on my task list.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `UPDATE` you plan to do is just fine, assuming your `WHERE` clause accurately defines only those rows that contain `\\OLDLOCATION\`, and that you have tested that your `REPLACE` doesn't remove any false positives (e.g. maybe you have an `\\OLDLOCATION\` reference in a comment that should stay intact).

Note that the `msdb` tables are shipped with SQL Server but they are not "off limits" like system tables (which you can't update in modern versions of SQL Server anyway). These tables are updated directly by SSMS, just like you would do so yourself with your own `UPDATE` (and just like they would be updated by the PowerShell script Thomas suggested - it doesn't do anything differently other than perform the update one row at a time).

Comment: Thanks for this. Since other time-consuming tasks have popped up meaning I can't indulge in powershell learning at the moment I've gone with the direct update approach. I took a copy of `dbo.sysjobsteps` first and ran the update with very carefully defined where clause and replace conditions. It seems to have worked fine - we've since run a handful of the jobs with the results we expected. Thanks very much for your advice. Regardless of the approach this time I'll definitely be investigating powershell further in the near future.